# How can I add a while loop in this script to run only the case statement again?

Tags: linux, bash

this is a script I'm working on for my Linux class. I would like to add a while loop to rerun the case statement =. any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date -d "$1" +"%m_%d_%Y");

clear

echo -n  " Have you finished everything?"
read response
if [ $response = "Y" ] || [ $response = "y" ]; then 

echo "Do you want a cookie?"

exit 

elif [ $response = "N" ] || [ $response = "n" ]; then 

echo "1 - Update Linux debs"

echo "2 - Upgrade Linux"

echo "3 - Backup your Home directory"

read answer 

case $answer in 

1) echo "Updating!"

    sudo apt-get update;;

2) echo "Upgrading!"

    sudo apt-get upgrade;;

3) echo "Backing up!"

    tar -cvf backup_on_$DATE.tar /home;;

esac

echo "Would you like to choose another option?"

read condition
fi
```

Comment: Since you're already using a numeric option index, you might want to consider using the `select` construct

Comment: please try not to bring here homework. I wont mind to spend a significant chunk of time helping other, however it is important you apply what you know, otherwise you are not learning. Besides the usefulness to others of this article is limited, the case is very specific, and most probably, duplicated. The answer to how to use while is at the distance of a 1-min google query.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I understand what you are saying but i been trying different ways of putting the while loop in my script and it keeps coming back with errors.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html

Answer (score 0):

```
while true; do
  #your code
  #break to break the infinite loop
  break
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you're doing this for a class, and I know there has been recent talk of not just giving out pure answers, but to try and help guide the user toward discovering the correct answer for themselves.  This is often done via comments in the form of questions (a.k.a. The Socratic Method).  I find this method to be a little too round-about, because an answer should be just that -- an answer -- and a *full* answer that is not vague enough to confuse users who are new to the things they are asking questions about.

If you are looking for a way to specifically re-use your `case` statement, then this is not the answer for you.  However, if you are open to going about this in another method using pure `if/else` logic and a couple of `functions`, then I would suggest doing it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# try to refrain from setting variables in all-caps,
# which could possibly override default shell environment variables
# not exactly sure why you're passing an argument to date here,
# but that's beside the point. For my own purposes, I will comment it out
# and just make the variable of today's date
# DATE="$(date -d "$1" +"%m_%d_%Y")"
date="$(date +%m_%d_%Y)"
clear

# read -p prompts for user input and then sets the response as a variable
read -p "Have you finished everything? [y/n] " response

# with single brackets, you can use the -o flag to represent "or"
# without having to include additional conditional brackets
if [ "$response" = "Y" -o "$response" = "y" ]; then
  echo "Do you want a cookie?"
  exit
elif [ "$response" = "N" -o "$response" = "n" ]; then
  echo "1 - Updadate Linux Debs"
  echo "2 - Upgrade Linux"
  echo "3 - Backup your Home directory"
else
  echo error.
  exit
fi

do_stuff() {
  read -p "Choose an option: [1-3] " answer
  if [[ $answer = 1 ]]; then
    echo "Updating!"
    sudo apt-get update
  elif [[ $answer = 2 ]]; then
    echo "Upgrading!"
    sudo apt-get upgrade
  elif [[ $answer = 3 ]]; then
    echo "Backing up!"
    tar -cvf "backup_on_${date}.tar" /home
  else
    echo error.
    exit
  fi
  do_again
}

do_again() {
  read -p "Would you like to choose another option? [y/n] " condition
  if [ "$condition" = "y" -o "$condition" = "Y" ]; then
    do_stuff
  else
    echo goodbye.
    exit
  fi
}

do_stuff
```

Comment: thanks for all the help. I need to have case statements and if then with a while loop or a for loop. I figured a for loop will just be a little different to me rather than the while loop. I have done the loop before but never in the middle of a script. thanks.

Comment: Ah! So I provided a bit of knowledge while not helping you cheat on your homework.  I'll consider it a success!  Also, *pssst*...check out @PSkocik's answer...*cough*